# SQL - Nested Selection Not Respecting Outer Limitation

Tags: mysql

I'm a MySQL beginner, trying to figure out how it works. I thought I was getting it until I ran the following:

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT COUNT(task_user.task_id = tasks.id) FROM task_user
    ) A
FROM
    tasks
```

I thought this would yield, for each row, the number of rows in `task_user` that had a `user_id` matching the `id` of the **current row from `tasks`**. To my dismay, instead I got a series of identical rows:

```
A:
--
29
29
29
29
29
29
29
29
29
```

The total number of matches altogether. Does anyone know how to do what I'm wishing? And can anyone explain why the above is my result?

Comment: Do `GROUP BY` over a `JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks, @PM77 but again, I'm new to SQL. Could you write an answer showing this, and - more importantly - explain why what I'm thinking is wrong?

Comment: Please post some sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Noob mistake..

So, I was expecting to get total of the number of rows where `tasks.id = task_user.task_id`. By running `COUNT` I was counting both TRUE and FALSE values

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT COUNT(task_user.task_id = tasks.id) FROM task_user
    ) A
FROM
    tasks
```

I just replaced `COUNT` with `SUM` and it works fine.

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT SUM(task_user.task_id = tasks.id) FROM task_user
    ) A
FROM
    tasks
```

Comment: A more typical way to do this would be: `SELECT COUNT(\`tasks\`.\`id\`) FROM \`tasks\` LEFT JOIN \`task_user\` ON \`task_user\`.\`task_id\` = \`tasks\`.\`id\``

Comment: @Lightness, It's probably cuz I'm not providing much information (which, I'll eventually try to fix) - but your statement does something very different than what I'm actually trying to accomplish. Yours finds the total number of `tasks` plus the number of additional records in `task_user` (when multiple) that point to `tasks.id`. My goal (perhaps unclear?) is actually to find *for each task* the number of records in `task_user` that point to `tasks.id`. Thanks though :)

Comment: Er, right, I meant this: `SELECT COUNT(\`task_user\`.\`task_id\`) FROM \`tasks\` JOIN \`task_user\` ON \`task_user\`.\`task_id\` = \`tasks\`.\`id\` GROUP BY \`tasks\`.\`id\`` ([demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0ee67/5))

Comment: Your way is quite elegant though, except for the subquery ;)